# Trigger SOQL Question

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I have a SOQL query that puts values into a map. In the main function of the trigger,(which lives within a for loop) I would like to clear() the original map, and re-run the same SOQL query, resulting in new map results.

Is there a way to do this? It's almost like I would be calling a method who's main function would be to run a SOQL query...

```
trigger calcSum2 on Lead (before insert, before update) 
{
    Set<Date> dates = new Set<Date>();
    Set<String> property = new Set<String>();
    Set<Integer> numOfGuests = new Set<Integer>();
    Set<String> region = new Set<String>();
    Map<Date, Decimal> cost = new Map<Date, Decimal>();
    Map<Date, String> undates = new Map<Date, String>();
    Set<String> appProps = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> availProps = new Set<String>();  
    Map<Date, Decimal> compareCosts = new Map<Date, Decimal>();
    Lead[] validLeads = new Lead[0];

    for(Lead record: Trigger.new)
    {
        if (record.Override_Rate_Total__c == false)
        {
            record.Rate_total__c = 0;

                if(record.Arrival_Date__c != null && record.Departure_Date__c != null && record.Property__c != null) 
                {
                    validLeads.add(record);
                    Date tempDate = record.Arrival_Date__c;                //Store Lead Arrival Date
                    String tempProperty = record.Property__c;              //Store Lead Property
                    Integer tempNumOfGuests = (Integer) (record.of_Adults__c + record.Number_of_Children__c);
                    String tempRegion = record.New_Region__c;
                    property.add(tempProperty);                            //Add Lead Property to property SET
                    numOfGuests.add(tempNumOfGuests);
                    region.add(tempRegion);

                    while(tempDate < record.Departure_Date__c)             //While Lead Arrival Date is less than Lead Departure Date, Add the date to the dates SET and cycle 1 day forward.
                    {
                        dates.add(tempDate);                               
                        tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);
                    }
                }
        }        
    }

    for(Property_Rate__c record:[SELECT Property__c, Rate__c,Date__c, Status__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Date__c IN :dates AND Property__c IN :property])    //Query Property rates for the property and between the dates
        {
            if (record.Status__c == 'Available' && record.Rate__c != null)                        //If the Property Rate is available and the rate is not NULL...
            {                                                                                                                                                   
                cost.put(record.Date__c, record.Rate__c);                                        //Map date-rate relationship and add to cost MAP
            }
            else                                                                                                 //Otherwise...
            {
                undates.put(record.Date__c, record.Status__c);                                   //Add to Unavailability undates MAP
            }                                                                                                    
        }
```

******Then I wish to change important criteria on the Lead

```
Lead.Property__c = //something else
```

******Now I wish to re-run the same SOQL query in order to run it with this new criteria.

Comment: Can you post some code (or pseudocode) to demonstrate what you're describing? At the moment your question is not clear enough to give you an answer.

Comment: @MarkPond Yes give me just one moment to gather it. I will try to simplify it

Comment: @MarkPond I'm not sure if you are notified automatically, but I've posted a sample

Comment: @AlexBrigham what is your question then? What issue have you encountered if you try to rerun the same query?

Comment: @LanceShi I simply don't know how to do it! The Query is outside of the for loop where my trigger's main function is. I just need to know how to re-run it from inside my trigger's main function!

Comment: @AlexBrigham I will try to give an answer to it as it is too large to put here as a comment. However, I am not sure whether this answers your question since it seems too obvious to me. Just let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: @LanceShi Ok thank you. Who knows, I might just be over looking something.

Comment: @AlexBrigham, loosely related to your question, how are you determining a different "property" within the trigger to assign? Didn't someone/something choose a specific property that they were interested in? It seems like you could switch around the logic in the trigger to first look for available dates per property and then run the logic to calc the guest count/region/cost, etc after you have 'good' property references on the Leads.

Answer (score 0):

Not whether this is what you are looking for. But this section is too big to put into a comment so does this looks what you are looking after?

```
    if(Util.inLeadTrigger) //put a static variable in Util class and set it to be false by default
    {
        return;
    }

    Map<Date, Decimal> cost = new Map<Date, Decimal>();
    Map<Date, String> undates = new Map<Date, String>();

    for(Property_Rate__c record:[SELECT Property__c, Rate__c,Date__c, Status__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Date__c IN :dates AND Property__c IN :property])    //Query Property rates for the property and between the dates
    {
        if (record.Status__c == 'Available' && record.Rate__c != null)                        //If the Property Rate is available and the rate is not NULL...
        {                                                                                                                                                   
            cost.put(record.Date__c, record.Rate__c);                                        //Map date-rate relationship and add to cost MAP
        }
        else                                                                                                 //Otherwise...
        {
            undates.put(record.Date__c, record.Status__c);                                   //Add to Unavailability undates MAP
        }                                                                                                    
    }

    //Handle the logic

    property.clear();

    for(Lead record : Trigger.new)
    {
        Lead.Property__c = //something else
        property.add(Lead.Property__c);
    }

    //Run your loop again, should put into a static method somewhere
    for(Property_Rate__c record:[SELECT Property__c, Rate__c,Date__c, Status__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Date__c IN :dates AND Property__c IN :property])    //Query Property rates for the property and between the dates
    {
        if (record.Status__c == 'Available' && record.Rate__c != null)                        //If the Property Rate is available and the rate is not NULL...
        {                                                                                                                                                   
            cost.put(record.Date__c, record.Rate__c);                                        //Map date-rate relationship and add to cost MAP
        }
        else                                                                                                 //Otherwise...
        {
            undates.put(record.Date__c, record.Status__c);                                   //Add to Unavailability undates MAP
        }                                                                                                    
    }

    //Handle the logic after resetting the map
```

Comment: So you are thinking just physically write the SOQL query again after handling some of the logic? It might work, and I will give it a try. But it would be Ideal if I could re-run the query within the logic (without having to exit and re-enter)

Comment: What do you worry about for re-running the SOQL query? SOQL limit or something else? If you are approaching the SOQL limit, you can choose to use one SOQL solution and put them into two different result lists and result maps using an extra loop. However, since it introduced an extra loop, I don't think it will save you any execution time.

Comment: It's just that I didn't want to put a SOQL query into a loop where my trigger's function lives; In order to bulkify correctly. Is it possible for me to call this query like a method? ex) query();

Comment: @AlexBrigham there are no queries within loops in either your code or Lance's. Both are generally considered 'bulkified', even if you believe your logic could be improved to remove the second query.

Comment: @MarkPond Hey Mark, I was trying to simplify the problem by only posting the important parts of the code. It is about 180 lines altogether

Comment: @AlexBrigham I guess the major problem is which part is having a query inside a loop?